# How to find label control in the RowCommand method of grid view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
GridViewRow clickedRow = ((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
Label lblUser = clickedRow.FindControl("lblFullName") as Label;
Label lblUserId = (Label)clickedRow.FindControl("lblUserId");
```

Compiler throwing error as

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your current code is that the GridView's `RowCommand` event is raised by gridview itself and not by an individual control thus your cast will fail:-

```
(LinkButton)sender
```

Because sender here is `Gridview` and not linkbutton.

Now, you may have multiple controls in your gridview which can raise this event(or you may add them in future) so add a `CommandName` attribute to your LinkButton like this:-

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="myLinkButton" runat="server" Text="Status" 
     CommandName="myLinkButton"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Finally in the `RowCommand` event you can first check if the event is raised by the `LinkButton` and then safely use the `e.CommandSource` property which will be a `LinkButton` and from there find the containing row of Gridview.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.CommandName == "myLinkButton")
   {
      LinkButton lnk = (e.CommandSource) as LinkButton;
      GridViewRow clickedRow = lnk.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
   }
}
```